# Tensor product of algebras which is Frobenius.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite dimensional algebras over a field $k$. Let us suppose that the $k$-algebra $A\otimes_{k} B$ is Frobenius (or symmetric).

Is it true that $A$ and $B$ are two Frobenius (symmetric) algebras ?

It is clear that the converse is true. If $A$ and $B$ are Frobenius, then one can construct an associative non-degenerate bilinear map on $A\otimes_{k} B$ using the ones on $A$ and $B$.

Thank you for your help!